# How do I make the system linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If i have four vectors, say for example,

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  k&2&1&2\\
  1&k&0&0\\
  2&3&0&1\\
  k-2&0&0&0
\end{array}
\right] $$

what would the values of 'k' be for the system to be linearly independant? I know that when the solution is non trivial, as in the solution is not 0, then the solution is linearly dependent, otherwise it is independent. But what value do I have to put for 'k' for it to be linearly independent. If anyone could help, it would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The columns are linearly independent if and only if the determinant of the matrix is non-zero.

Comment: By permuting rows and columns one easily makes this matrix triangular.

Answer (score 1):

It will be linearly independent for $k \not= 0,2$ since determinant of this matrix is $k(k-2)$.